# How can I change the code that if the goForward state change in runtime or at start move the transform forward or backward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public bool go;
    public bool goForward;

    private int index = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private int c = 0;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();

    public int numofposbetweenpoints;

    private bool getonce;

    private void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").GetComponent<Waypoints>();

        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (getonce == false)
        {
            numofposbetweenpoints = curvedLinePoints.Count;

            getonce = true;
        }

        if (go == true && waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count > 0)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            // error exception out of bound on line 55 to check !!!!!
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index], distanceToTravel);

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne)
                    {
                        index--;

                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

Now it's moving from the first index to the last one then when reaching the last index it's moving from the last index to the first one and so on nonstop.

but I want that if goForward is true at the start to go to the first index to the last then from last to the first like it is now but if goForward will be false at the start then start from the last index move in reverse to the first index and then from the first index to the last same as the first state but opposite.

and if I change the goForward at run time then change the transform moving direction to the last/before index it was and keep moving on that direction. and if I change the flag at a run time again change direction again so I can change the direction/s in real time.

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the code that if the goForward state change in runtime or at start move the transform forward or backward?

Consider using the mathematical `%`(modulo) operator. This operator performs 'clock  math'. Think of it like a hand on a clock, when it reaches 12 on the clock the hand 'wraps around' the the beginning and starts as 1. Take the number 4 for example. If we have a loop like

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i % 4}");
}
```

It would produce 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3. This in-effect gives you a looping index around the number 4.

If we look at this in the context of an array(or list) we can loop through an array, forwards AND backwards without ever checking to see if we are at the first or last position of the array(or list).

This effect is super helpful for traveling between arbitrary waypoints and avoiding that pesky `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You could implement something like this to achieve the effect you want:

```cs
    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            // error exception out of bound on line 55 to check !!!!!
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index], distanceToTravel);

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // determine if we should go forward or backward through the list
                int direction = goForward ? 1 : -1;

                // loop around the index, this automatically wraps to 0 if we are going forward and get to the end of the list,
                //  or to the end if we are going backwards and hit the end of the list
                index = (index + direction) % waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count;

                // increment the amounnt of points we passed
                counter++;
                if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                {
                    c++;

                    counter = 0;
                }

                // reset C if we reached the end
                if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                {
                    c = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
```